# How to push the data from api to my initial state list items using the redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm currently new on react redux toolkit and now I am practicing on this management. Right now I want to do is to push all datas from my api to my initial state list_remarks reducers.

Question: How or where to put my api to push all the datas from api to my initial state list?

**Ex API: localhost:8000/api/list_remarks**

Here is my CreateSlice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const RemarksSlice = createSlice({
    name:"check_in_remarks",
    initialState: {
        list_remarks:[],
        check_in_remarks: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        list_remarks: (state, action) => {
            state.remarks = action.payload
        },
        add_check_in_remarks: (state, action) => {
            state.check_in_remarks = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const { add_check_in_remarks, list_remarks } = RemarksSlice.actions;

export const AddRemarks = (state) => state.check_in_remarks.check_in_remarks;
export const ListRemarks = (state) => state.list_remarks.list_remarks;

export default RemarksSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: can you show api calling part

Comment: @JohnLobo sorry what do you mean api calling part?

Comment: can you show where you calling api .i dont see any api call code.as per your question,you wanted to set api response to redux state so asked

Comment: I don't have yet calling api yet because I don't know where should I put this function, I think that's the main problem to solve my question. can you help me for this? how to create this calling api?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `createAsyncThunk`
Ref:https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

I can provide you basic snippet which might help you

```
export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk(
    'posts/getPosts',

    async (arg, { dispatch, getState, extra, requestId, signal, rejectWithValue }) => {
      
        return fetch(
            `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=${arg.limit}`
        ).then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                
                return rejectWithValue([], "api url not found from");
            }
            return res.json()
        }).catch(error => {
           
            return rejectWithValue([], error);
           
        })
    }

)
```

In createSlice

```
    export const RemarksSlice = createSlice({
    name:"check_in_remarks",
    initialState: {
        list_remarks:[],
        check_in_remarks: null,
status :null
    },
    reducers: {
        list_remarks: (state, action) => {
            state.remarks = action.payload
        },
        add_check_in_remarks: (state, action) => {
            state.check_in_remarks = action.payload
        }
    },
     extraReducers: {

        [getPosts.pending]: (state, action) => {
          
            state.status = 'loading'
        },
        [getPosts.fulfilled]: (state, { payload, meta }) => {

          
            state.list_remarks = payload
            state.status = 'success'
        },
        [getPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
        },
    }
})
```

To dispatch from any useEffect or anywhere you wanted then

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPosts({ limit: 5 }));
       
    }, [])
```

Comment: Hi my last question, using this createAsyncThunk is realtime? let say when I add new item it will automatically display it on the list?

Comment: if you see doc :A function that accepts a Redux action type string and a callback function that should return a promise. It generates promise lifecycle action types based on the action type prefix that you pass in, and returns a thunk action creator that will run the promise callback and dispatch the lifecycle actions based on the returned promise.

Comment: it will call whenever you dispatch

Comment: Hi, One last question where should i put the useSelector so that to get the auth token?

Comment: in your component where you want to use auth token

Comment: I need to put autherization header on my api. so probably inside your getPosts I need to create a variable and call it the useSelector state token

Comment: but the problem when i put the useSelector I got error of React Hook "useSelector" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function 
 react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: no need to useselector inside because you get all state in getState()

Comment: how to call the token const token = useSelector((state) => state.user.user.token);

Comment: const {user}=getState(); user.token

Answer (score 0):

add action setRemarks and setError:

```
reducers: {
...
   // Getting a list of remarks in a store
   setRemarks: (state, action) => {
      state.remarks = action.payload
   }
   // In case of problems with receiving, we will add an error to the store.
   setError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload
   }
... 
}
```

and add asyncThunk ([about createAsyncThunk function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)):

```
   export const fetchRemaks = createAsyncThunk(
   'remarks/fetch',
   async (_, {dispatch}) => {
    // here is your receiving remarks function
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(remarks => dispatch(setRemarks(remarks)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(setError(error)))
   }
)
```

How to use:

```
export default function App() {
  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { error } = useSelector(state => state.remarks)
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    dispatch(fetchRemaks())
    setLoading(false)
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
     {error && <b>{error}</b>}
     {loading 
        ? 'loading...'
        : 'remarks'
     }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi do I need to export this fetchRemaks?

Comment: you can create a separate asyncAction.js file and export this async action from it

Comment: How to use: like a normal action in the useEffect hook

Comment: Hi my last question, using this createAsyncThunk is realtime? let say when I add new item it will automatically display it on the list?

Comment: Hi, One last question where should i put the useSelector so that to get the auth token?